# Can statements in javascript begin with condition?

Tags: javascript

I came across a javascript code which had a for loop as follows :

```
for (d = 0; d < c / 8; d++)

0 === (d & 3) && (e = a[d / 4]), b += String.fromCharCode(e >>> 24), e <<= 8;
```

What does this mean -> `0 === (d & 3) && (e = a[d / 4])`

And does the comma have any special role here or is it simply used to convert both the statements separated by it as one.
Can anyone please explain this to me ...

Comment: you are looking at minified javascript code.

Comment: That is either purposefully obfuscated, or someone was trying to be clever and ended up obfuscating the code…

Comment: Bitwise operators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators